# Change a large dynamodb table to use LSIs instead of GSIs

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a live table in dynamo with about 28 million records in it.
The table has a number of GSI that I'd like to change to be LSIs however LSIs can only be created when the table is created.

I need to create a new table and migrate the data with minimum downtime.  I was thinking I'd do the following:
Create the new table with the correct indexes.
Update the code to write records to the old and new table. When this starts, take a note of the timestamp for the first record.
Write a simple process to sync existing data for anything with a create date prior to my first date.
I'd have to add a lock field to the new table to prevent race conditions when an existing record is updated.
When it's all synced we'd swap to using the new table.

I think that will work, but it's fairly complicated and feels prone to error.  Has anyone found a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach:

(Let's refer to the table with GSIs as oldTable and the new table with LSIs as newTable).

1. Create newTable with the required LSIs.
2. Create a [DynamoDB tirgger](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.Lambda.html) for the oldTable such that for every new record coming to the oldTable insert the same record to the newTable. (This logic needs to be in the AWS Lambda).
3. Make your application point to the newTable.
4. Migrate all the records from oldTable to newTable.

Comment: I didn't know about triggers, I'll experiment and update.